# Force https wordpess into a prestashop (.htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https, prestashop

We have an online store developed in prestashop with a blog section created in wordpress, the prestashop has the https forced, but the blog when I try to force the https shows error 500.

I try a lot of configs, but all produced the error 500, can help me ?

Example (Wordpress blog):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/blog/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Did  you change the values of 'siteurl' and 'home' inside wp_options table?

Comment: Yes i changed the "siteurl" and "home".

Comment: Step 1: Go check what the server’s error log has to say.

Comment: Problem solved, the website had the Cloudflare config and the https service was activate ... when i disabled it my htaccess works fine!

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Make sure you keep wordpess default htaccess code, simply by delete the .htaccess file visit site from browser it will regenete default code and add Step 2 code after end of it.

Or you can add default htaccess code like below,

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

**Step 2**

To force all traffic on your domain to use HTTPS, simply add the following. If you have existing code in your .htaccess file, you should add this above your current rewrite rules.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```